# Problem with counting the data for a specific key

Tags: python, api, data-science, data-analysis

W​hy len(data) does not give me the info for a specific country. What function should I use instead of it.???

```
import requests  
import pandas as pd
import json  

api_url="https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/Accessing%20Data%20Using%20APIs/jobs.json?utm_medium=Exinfluencer&utm_source=Exinfluencer&utm_content=000026UJ&utm_term=10006555&utm_id=NA-SkillsNetwork-Channel-SkillsNetworkCoursesIBMDA0321ENSkillsNetwork21426264-2022-01-01"
 

locations=["Los Angeles", "New York", "San Francisco"]

def get_number_of_jobs_Loc_list(locations):
    number_of_jobs_list = []
    for location in locations:
        payload={"Location":location}
        response=requests.get(api_url, params=payload)
        if response.ok:
            data=response.json()
            number_of_jobs = len(data)
            number_of_jobs_list.append({location: number_of_jobs})
            
    return number_of_jobs_list
get_number_of_jobs_Loc_list(locations)
```

T​he output is:

```
[{'Los Angeles': 27005}, {'New York': 27005}, {'San Francisco': 27005}]
```

Comment: What's the problem? What your code produce and how is different from what you want?

Comment: {'Los Angeles': 640},
 {'New York': 3226},
 {'San Francisco': 435} the output should be like this ->  function to find number of jobs in US for a location of your choice

Comment: I tried your code, the API gave 27005 for 'Los Angeles', why this number should be 640?

Comment: there are different cities. And the result is the same for all cities(it should be different). If you look at the json file there are job openings for a specific city. Hence I want to count them separately. Number should be 640 because the result is so for most of people, although my code is exactly the same as theirs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong and certainly more complex than it needs to be.

The query parameters are not needed. The value of 27005 is the number of jobs in total (across all cities). This will do what you need:

```
import requests  
 
URL = 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module 1/Accessing Data Using APIs/jobs.json'

locations = ['Los Angeles', 'San Francisco', 'New York']

def get_number_of_jobs_Loc_list():
    jobs = {}
    (response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
    for d in response.json():
        location = d['Location']
        jobs[location] = jobs.get(location, 0) + 1
    return jobs

jobs = get_number_of_jobs_Loc_list()

for location in locations:
    print(f'Number of jobs in {location} = {jobs.get(location, 0)}')
```

**Output:**

```
Number of jobs in Los Angeles = 640
Number of jobs in San Francisco = 435
Number of jobs in New York = 3226
```